# Puppeteer can´t get iframe

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I´m trying to get content of a frame with puppeteer and get "Error: No node found for selector: #ctl00_PlaceContent_txtMes"

This is de code:

```
// Get the username and password inputs
const browser = await Apify.launchPuppeteer();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("https://servicioscorp.anses.gob.ar/MiAnsesSitio/Sistemas/InvocaSistemas.aspx?IdMenu=10603");
// Login
await page.type('#Usuario', "user");
await page.type('#Clave',"key");
let n,x;
 for (n=0 ; n <= 3000 ; n++) { console.log(n)     }
await page.click('#Ingresar');
await page.waitForNavigation()
await page.click('#ctl00_MenuIzquierdo_rpt_MenuPadre_ctl05_lnk_Padre')
await page.click('#ctl00_MenuIzquierdo_rpt_MenuPadre_ctl05_rpt_MenuHijos_ctl02_lnk')
await page.waitForNavigation()
const frame = await page.frames().find(frame => frame.name() === 'ctl00_PlaceContent_icontenedor');
await frame.waitForSelector('#ctl00_PlaceContent_txtMes')
await frame.type('#ctl00_PlaceContent_txtMes','01');
await page.type('#ctl00_PlaceContent_txtMes','01');
await page.type("#ctl00_PlaceContent_txtAnio","2021");
await page.click("#ctl00_PlaceContent_btnConsultar");
await page.waitForNavigation();
    await page.waitForNavigation()
       await page.waitForSelector("ctl00_PlaceContent_gvConceptos").then(() => {
            const innerText =  page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#ctl00_PlaceContent_gvConceptos').innerText);
            page.waitForNavigation()
            const div =  page.$("#ctl00_PlaceContent_tlb_General_Grilla")
            let Contenido;
        })
console.log('Done.');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: so no node was found with the selector ig.. also, `window.frames` is a nice place to find frames

Comment: Is it the same origin?

Comment: Sorry, don´t understand. What do you mean with same origin? How do I use window.frames?

Comment: Is there a typo in these two lines? `await frame.type('#ctl00_PlaceContent_txtMes','01');
await page.type('#ctl00_PlaceContent_txtMes','01');` — Do both page and frame contain elements with the same id?